# Javascript (typescript) error. Classes undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a simple app, with the following js:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {    
       class playField {   
       }

       class Row {    
       }

       class Game {     
       }

       class pcFunctions {    
       }
       var game = new Game();
   });
```

Note that I removed class code, because I think it is not important to answer my question. The idea is that I want to create a game object (the Game object creates the playField and the pcFunctions, while the playField creates Row objects).

Now when I just run this in my browser, game is undefined. Every class except  is undefined actually. Obviously I'm making some kind of mistake in my thinking of the functionality. I however can't figure out what. Could someone explain me what is wrong and in what way I should implement this kind of functionality?

Comment: Where *exactly* is `game` undefined? It's a local variable in the document.ready event so if you're trying to access it outside it then of course it's undefined.

Comment: Hey Juhana, yeah Im a beginner so that's probably the problem. So how should I deal with the problem:
I want to create the game object of the Game class after everything is loaded (Hence why it is at the bottom), but the object must remain alive for me to work with. (I see now why this does not work, but how could I make it work?

Comment: Why would you want to define everything in the document.ready event? You're not doing anything with the DOM so there's no apparent need for it. If you *really* have to have it in the document.ready, just declare the variable as global outside the callback.

Comment: Ok it all sounds a bit confusing to me. I just started programming, but someone told me placing most js in the doc.ready event is good practice. (maybe I understood it wrong). But I will refer to the DOM, so I do want to keep it in this function. What do you mean by 'declare the variable as global outside the callback'? Basically I just want the classes to live when my browser is done loading. Don't I have to return all those classes then? In any case, thank you for your help

Comment: Many people think that placing everything in the document.ready is good practice, but many people also think that Earth is flat and the government is reading our minds with alien technology. The short version: remove the document.ready event when you *define* the classes and use it only when you *use* those classes.

Comment: In this case the object game _can_ exist out of scope since the `var` keyword is used. The most likely problem is that it is referred before the document ready function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

1,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {    
       class playField {   
       }

       class Row {    
       }

       class Game {     
       }

       class pcFunctions {    
       }
       var game = new Game();
       //game => "undefined"?
   });
```

for case 1, no idea, it should have game object..

2,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {    
           class playField {   
           }

           class Row {    
           }

           class Game {     
           }

           class pcFunctions {    
           }
           var game = new Game();

       });
 //game =>undefined?
// windows.game => undefined?
```

for case 2 because you defined and instanced your game object inside document.ready handler function, therefore it only can exist inside that function scope.